# Computing Mallows' Cp with SAS

Tags: regression, sas

I have a question about SAS:

How do you get the parameter estimate for Mallows' Cp procedure in SAS?

Comment: Anything missing in the [PROC REG](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect007.htm) documentation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CP option on the MODEL statement in PROC REG. This writes the Cp statistic to the OUTEST= data set:

```
proc reg data=sashelp.class outest=est;
model weight = height / cp;
run;
proc print data=est; run;
```

See http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect013.htm